# Redirect without telling the browser

Tags: php, redirect, browser, responsive-design

I have created a very responsive website using a template at w3layouts.com.
Which supports all desktop, java phones, smartphones.

So, you can download any template from that website to see how it works.
It first sees if the user is using a pc, a java mobile or a smartphone. And if he is on pc a php variable $browser_t is set to web, if the user is on mobile the variable is set to mobile and if the user is on smartphone then the variable is set to smartphone. In the template there are three folders web, mobile, smartphone. The template index.php checks the users device and then includes the specific file in the specific folder i.e web, mobile or smartphone. e.g if on mobile the user asks for www.mysite.com/hello.php the .htacces file will go to index.php and the index.php will include www.mysite.com/mobile/hello.php.

But I want to use get requests in my website so I changed the index.php file to send a header like:

```
header('Location: mysite.com/'.$browser_t.'/'.$page_name);
```

$page_name is the variable which holds the 'hello.php' part of the url.

But the problem is that I don't want the user to know how the url changed. So is there a way to redirect to a different page without telling the users browser that the page is redirected.

Comment: You can create a global div and refresh that div on every request using AJAX.

Comment: Why would you want that? Presenting URLs to the user is a good feature so they can copy links and send them and whomever uses the link will see the same result without having to add "clikc on X, then on Y and then on Z". If you want to hide the fact that you use hello.php, use mod_rewrite instead: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @HeroFTime Can you tell this as an answer with more explanation?

Comment: @user3471510 - That would be a basically page refresh through ajax. Just after <body> tag, create for example a <div> tag and wrap your content in that. Then use AJAX to change the content of the div, in this case, page wont be refreshing but the content will be changing as desired by you. Send your GET or POST data in it as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very appreciated but you can use this trick. Create different index files including one index.php, index_main.php , index_mobile.php . Now in you index.php file use this code

```
switch ($browser_t){
    case "<your main view case>":
        include "index_main.php";
        break;
    case "<your mobile view case>":
        include "index_mobile.php";
        break;
    # and so on
}
```

Comment: But how do I use the $_GET method?